# Labels Are Out Of Place When Creating Pie Chart Using R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am having a hard time figuring out why my labels are out of place.
[See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmVQt.png)

My Script:

```
ggplot(data = percentage2, aes(x = "", y = minutes, fill = lbls)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, color = 1) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = 1.5, 
                       label = paste0(round(minutes, 2), "%")), 
                   size = 4.5, nudge_x = 0.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void() +
  labs(title = "Percentage of Active Minutes", y = "Activity") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Activity Level", 
                      breaks = c("Sedentary", "Lightly Active", "Fairly Active", "Very Active"))
```

**lbls** 
Very Active
Fairly Active
Lightly Active 
Sedentary

**minutes** 
1.736602
1.113014
15.820493
81.329891

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each label has been placed at the end of each section instead to the midpoint. You could by forward calculate the positions in a different dataframe and use these for your `geom_lable_repel`. You can use the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df = data.frame(lbls = c("Very Active", "Fairly Active", "Lightly Active", "Sedentary"),
                minutes = c(1.636, 1.113, 16.82, 81.33))

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    cs = rev(cumsum(rev(minutes))), 
    pos = minutes/2 + lead(cs, 1),
    pos = if_else(is.na(pos), minutes/2, pos))

ggplot(df, aes(x = "" , y = minutes, fill = fct_inorder(lbls))) +
  geom_col(width = 1) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0 ) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Activity Level", breaks=c("Sedentary", "Lightly Active", "Fairly Active", "Very Active")) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(y = pos, label = paste0(minutes, "%")), data = df2, size=4, show.legend = F, nudge_x = 1) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I have a few quesitons:
1. What do you mean by me placing the labels at the end?
2. I also just figured out how the calculation works for both cs and pos (what does this mean?) columns, but what is this "pos = if_else(is.na(pos), minutes/2, pos))" doing? Is it overriding the first pos if it finds null values?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `geom_col` uses `position="stack"` while `geom_label_repel` uses `position = "identity"`. To fix that use `position = position_stack()` for the labels too. Note however that you can't have nudging with `position_stack()`. Instead I went for using `vjust=.5` to place the labels in the center of the bars and set `direction="y"`. You could also adjust the x to shift the labels to the outside.

```r
percentage2 <- data.frame(
  minutes = c(1.736602, 1.113014, 15.820493, 81.329891),
  lbls = c("Very Active", "Fairly Active", "Lightly Active", "Sedentary")
)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(data = percentage2, aes(x = "", y = minutes, fill = lbls)) +
  geom_col(width = 1, color = 1) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(x = 1.5, label = paste0(round(minutes, 2), "%")), 
                   size = 4.5, 
             show.legend = FALSE, position = position_stack(vjust = .5), direction = "y") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void() +
  labs(title = "Percentage of Active Minutes", y = "Activity") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Activity Level", 
                      breaks = c("Sedentary", "Lightly Active", "Fairly Active", "Very Active"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for at first but then I found out using nudge adds those lines to the respective pies, making the visualization cleaner.